# Should I use a delegate for a infinite loop running in the background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops, delegates

I want to have an app that repeatedly on a given interval of time (say, 5 seconds) will preform an HTTP GET request and update something (say, a view label) using the response. But this should run independently of what the user is doing. What is the appropriate way of doing this? My only current thought is creating a class that does this and just having the view controller use this class as a delegate. However, I'm fairly new to iOS and I'm skeptical that I'm going about this the right way. Any suggestions? Thank!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use NSTimer:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(HTTPRequest:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```

This will call your HTTPRequest method every 5.0 seconds.

Comment: Great! So what is NSTimer really doing here? When an object calls NSTimer does it create a separate thread? I guess I could also just look this part up myself now that I know what to look for though...

Answer (score 2):

> repeatedly on a given interval of time...will preform an HTTP GET request and update

That's called polling, and it's something you should avoid any way you can. One of the best ways to avoid it is to have the server tell you when something changes rather than continually asking. This is exactly what [push notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html) are designed to facilitate. Notifications will significantly reduce the number of network requests your app makes, and that conserves both battery power and the user's data plan.

So, if you can manage it, **use push notifications instead of polling**. The main exception is if you know that the thing you're retrieving will have changed each time you request it, you can't calculate the new value yourself, and you know that the user actually cares about seeing each new value.

> this should run independently of what the user is doing

If the only thing you're doing with the information is updating the display, then it really *shouldn't* run independently of what the user is doing. If you make this request every five seconds, that's 12 unnecessary requests every minute that the user is doing something other than looking at the result of the request. I can see the appeal of having an object that always has the current information available, but there's a real cost to that in terms of battery power and data transfer. (It also imposes an unnecessarily high load on your server.)

It's much better to fetch the data only when the user is likely to use it.

Comment: While the other answer actually gives the solution to what I asked about doing, this is also extremely good advice. I'll probably use the polling for testing out a few simple things for now, but I'll make sure to try to use push notifications when doing something more serious. Thanks!